# Why isn't asdf:load-system creating the package

Tags: package, common-lisp, asdf

I'm trying to to use asdf's functionality to run my test suite from the repl but when using quicklisps quickload if fails on the first attempt to load foo and success on the second.

```
(in-package :cl-user)
(defpackage :foo-system
  (:use :cl :asdf))
(in-package :foo-system)

(asdf:defsystem :foo
  :components ((:file "foo")))

(asdf:defsystem :foo-tests
  :depends-on (:foo)
  :components ((:file "foo-tests")))

(defmethod asdf:perform ((op test-op) (system (eql (find-system :foo))))
  (asdf:load-system 'foo-tests)
  (foo-tests:run-tests))
```

It makes sense because when I compile the asd file the error appears to be in the second form of the asdf:perfom defmethod. The error, replacing nclack by foo, is:

> ../../nclack/nclack.asd:36:27:   read-error: 
>       READ error during COMPILE-FILE:
>
> ```
>   Package NCLACK-TESTS does not exist.
>
>     Line: 36, Column: 27, File-Position: 1034
>
>     Stream: #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM
>               for "file /Users/PuercoPop/quicklisp/local-projects/nclack/nclack.asd"
>               {1005DB11A3}>
> ```

which matches the (foo-tests:run-tests) line. So it appears to be that 'loading' a system is different from compiling its forms? Or why is the package not defined after loading the system? Any ideas? I'm at a loss.

Comment: `find-system` is a function in `asdf` namespace. The same goes for `test-op`. That shouldn't compile otherwise / unless you had those symbols declared in a package which was current at the compilation time.

Comment: Thank you for catching another mistake I had. It now compiles if I remove the (foo:tests-run-tests) form but this is a different kind of error. I'm going to update the code in the question to fix the mistake you pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `compile-file` this:

```
(defmethod asdf:perform ((op test-op) (system (eql (find-system :foo))))
  (asdf:load-system 'foo-tests)
  (foo-tests:run-tests))
```

the first step is to `read` the entire form.  `Read`ing includes interning of all symbols found.  However, at read time, the form has not executed, so the system `foo-tests` is not yet loaded.  Since that system includes the package `foo-tests`, and that is not loaded yet either, you cannot intern any symbols into that package at read time of this form.

That's why `compile-file` gives the error shown when trying to `read` the form.

It seems to me that you would need to `(funcall (find-symbol "RUN-TESTS" #:foo-tests))`.

Comment: That could be, but the package name was/is different?

Comment: I think that the asking did not consistently replace his real system name with `foo` in the question.

Comment: Having had to do similar work-arounds for an assortment of reasons in the past, this seems to be one of the times where `(funcall (find-symbol ...))` is unavoidable (in the case where I recall having had to do this in the past, I was building a quick wrapper around CLX to allow saving and restoring the window state of an application across restarts).

Comment: Although (funcall (find-symbol "run-tests)) doesn't work, your answer makes it clear why it fails. I wasn't aware reading interned the symbols. Thank you for shedding light where was darkness.

Comment: Careful with the reader case.  "RUN-TESTS" names a different symbol than "run-tests".  Default reader case upcases symbol names.

Comment: PuercoPop just tried to amend this answer with the following (I have not verified it): It appears that asdf now includes the function asdf/package:symbol-call for this use case, as can be seen on iolib.

Answer (score 0):

First:

If you define a new package `FOO-SYSTEM` and *use* the package `ASDF` and then use the asdf symbols still with the prefix, then you kind of defeated the *using* of the package. Why use it, when you prefix the symbols anyway?

It is hard to say what the error is, since we don't see a backtrace and don't see the files.

Anyway, you need to make sure that a package is available during compilation of a file. For example compiling a `DEFPACKAGE` form may not change the compile-time environment. You need to execute the `DEFPACKAGE` form. You also need to make sure that the package definition gets loaded during a *load system* operation.

If the package does not exist, you need to make sure that it exists.

Comment: The definition of the foo system was an edit so the asdf prefix was a vestige of it, thank you from noticing it. You can see the backtrace [here][http://paste.lisp.org/+2YXG]

I am aware that I need to execute the defpackage form, the question is how do I use asdf to do so. Sorry is my question was unclear.